# How to detect marker on polyline in leaflet js

Tags: dictionary, leaflet

I have many polylines say A-B , C-D , E-F and so on . I have a marker (say H) at some location on the map . Now I drag and drop the marker on any of the above polylines . 
Upon dropping the marker on the polyline I want to change the color of that particular polyline . 
Can anyone please help me out in this ?
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: I haven't quite worked it out, but you might be able to use the `Leaflet.Snap` plugin to fire an event when a marker is dropped on a polyline. https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Snap